# Controlled impedance stackup questions

Tags: power, impedance, via, ground-loop, stack-up

In this stackup (I know that it is not the best stackup but it is a general question,) if I choose to use controlled impedance on `L4` (let's say 50 ohm), what is the reference that needs to `L4` signals?

It's a stripline so it should be two layers (3 and 5.)

Is it possible to route a stripline signal with only 1 reference layer in `L5`?

[image]

Comment: If you put no copper on L1, L2, and L3 above the L4 trace, you have buried microstrip line instead of stripline.

Comment: @ThePhoton If I have power plane IN L3 HOW DO I get 50 ohm control impedance that what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power & ground planes above/below Layer-4 are significant. This is a stripline.

If you routed on Layer-5 and keep it mostly as a plane, then you will have a coplaner stripline. Most of the effects will be between the ground plane on L5 and the trace. Any traces crossing the stripline conductor on L4 & L6 will affect the impedance. Generally, not recommended unless you can avoid crossing traces.

Comment: I asked about Layer-4, If I want that L4 will be 50-ohm control impedance, who will be the reference in this case?

Comment: @Knowledge The planes on L3 and L5 are the reference planes which make this a stripline. Bypass capacitors between L3 & L5 plus the capacitance between the layers join these layers in the AC realm.

Comment: Power plane could be a reference plane?

Comment: Yes, a power plane can be a reference plane. For best results there should be no breaks in the plane near the trace, and it should be well coupled (by capacitors) to the ground plane as mentioned by qrk.